# How to create an empty vector of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, vector

As I currently study Java in University but I am working on a C++ project. It is a text game in which I'm trying to create an empty vector of Item objects which I'm later going to add with the addItem(Item newItem) method of the Room object. The problem is that when in the constructor I try to set it so that every time a room is created, a new vector of Item objects is created with a capacity of the vector of 20, it gives me this error:

**'Item::Item': no appropriate default constructor available**

Here is the code:

**Item.hpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef Item_HPP
#define Item_HPP

class Item {

    std::string description;

public:
    Item(std::string description);
    std::string getDescription();
    void setDescription(std::string description);
    void use();
};

#endif
```

**Item.cpp:**

```
#include "Item.hpp"

Item::Item(std::string description) {

    this->description = description;
}

std::string Item::getDescription() {

    return this->description;
}

void Item::setDescription(std::string description) {

    this->description = description;
}

void Item::use() {

    std::cout << "You are using item: " << description << std::endl;
}
```

**Room.hpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Item.hpp"

#ifndef Room_HPP
#define Room_HPP


class Room {

    std::string description;
    static const int MAX_ITEMS = 20;
    std::vector <Item> items;
    int numberOfItems;


public:
    Room(std::string description);
    std::string getDescription();
    void addItem(Item newItem);
    std::vector<Item> getItems();

    Item getItem(std::string description);
};

#endif
```

**Room.cpp:**

```
#include "Room.hpp"

Room::Room(std::string description) {

    this->description = description;
    this->items = std::vector<Item>(20);
    this->numberOfItems = 0;
}

std::string Room::getDescription() {

    return this->description;
}

void Room::addItem(Item newItem) {

    if (numberOfItems < MAX_ITEMS) {
        this->items[numberOfItems] = newItem;
        numberOfItems++;
    }
}

std::vector<Item> Room::getItems() {

    return this->items;
}

Item Room::getItem(std::string description) {

    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;
    Item *target = NULL;
    while (!found && i < numberOfItems) {

        if (items[i].getDescription() == description) {

            target = &items[i];
            found = true;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return *target;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all of that code is really necessary to demonstrate the problem you have? I am not. Provide a [mcve] (emphasis on _minimal_) as required here please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hello as I am new to C++ I've been told by lecturers and teachers quite a lot that sometimes the problem in the code may not be in the place I think it might be, that's why I provided all the code which are part of the problem (as the program has more than 20 more classes), I am new to C++ and I am still learning the language, sorry for providing that much information!

Comment: You can simply reduce the code by commenting out unrelated stuff, and see if the error is still there. If not you've gone too far. After you have done that, the uncommented stuff is the essence you should post here.

Comment: Thank you I will keep that in mind for future question!

Comment: Also please [research a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+vector+error+no+default+constructor&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&sxsrf=ALeKk00la21l2UDc4ISt_l7QdB86HUd9jw:1609196871236&ei=R2XqX9z-DcuakwWlyoroAw&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwicvoi_5fHtAhVLzaQKHSWlAj04ChDy0wN6BAgIEDY&biw=1600&bih=789) before asking another question here.

Comment: I've been searching for the same problem as mine but as I already said I am quite new to the language and as I am self-learning (As I study Java and try to transfer my knowledge to C++ when I learn something in Java), I actually checked the topics I've been provided with but still could not understand the problem (I've tried to find a solution to my problem for a few days before posting), that's why I asked this question. Thank you again for your responses I will keep all that in mind for future questions!

Comment: As you can see from my link, it's fairly easy to get the relevant information. You can also do like I did and restrct the search by using `site:stackoverflow.com`. Google is way better than the Stack Overflow inbuild search feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly just [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) buffer for 20 elements and later add elements via [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

```
Room::Room(std::string description) {

    this->description = description;
    this->items = std::vector<Item>();
    this->items.reserve(20);
    this->numberOfItems = 0;
}

void Room::addItem(Item newItem) {

    if (numberOfItems < MAX_ITEMS) {
        if (numberOfItems == static_cast<int>(this->items.size())) {
            this->items.push_back(newItem);
        } else if (numberOfItems < static_cast<int>(this->items.size())) {
            this->items[numberOfItems] = newItem;
        } else {
            // unsupported to create gap between items
        }
        numberOfItems++;
    }
}
```

Comment: More clearly: `items = std::vector<Item>(20);` does not only reserve space for 20 items, it also _creates_ those 20 items.

Comment: ...and since you haven't said otherwise, those items all need to be default constructed.

Comment: is it possible to just initialise the vector with capacity of 20 in 1 line without the reserve() method without creating any items to it? And how can I create the array with the constructor I have created instead of the default one? Thank you for your earlier answer it helped me quite a lot!

Comment: @ShadeyyWasTaken • Change this `this->items = std::vector<Item>(20);` to this `this->items.reserve(20);`